# Send data from android to jsp page

Tags: android, jsp, connection

I'm creating an app that sends a string from android to a jsp.
Note that I'm new with both android and jsp.

Here is my code from Android

```
 String toBeSent = stringMeanR;
    String connection="http://127.0.0.1:8080/test-app/hello.jsp?data="+toBeSent;
    Intent accessTheJSP=new Intent();
    //accessTheJSP.setType("image/*");
    Log.i("Suma","Suma" + toBeSent);
    //accessTheJSP.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    accessTheJSP.setData(Uri.parse(connection));
    startActivity(accessTheJSP);
```

My code from the JSP is:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.math.*" %>
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %> 
...
String client= request.getParameter("data");
System.out.println(client);
 }
%>
```

The problem is that my result is null. Is this an option for sending data and if yes please tell mw why it is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in  String connection="http://10.0.2.2:8080/test-app/hello.jsp?data="+toBeSent;

If not replace 10.0.2.2 by your system IP it might work.

Answer (score 0):

try `startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(connection)));` to load your page in the browser.

Comment: Ok the problem is that when i simulate using my emulator it says that the webpage is down... the problem is frommy emulator, or android app. what can i do. I added as a permission the internet

Comment: Are your server running? can you load the page correctly from your desktop browser? If you have any exception can you post it.